# Concatanation in javascript error

Tags: javascript

My following javascript file displays nothing , although I was expecting a link there . Somebody please tell me the reason

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">

var u = 'somewebsite';
var q += '<a href="'+u+'">';
var q += '</a>';

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=q;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

several things going wrong here. First, as shelman says, q isn't being initialised. Secondly using var is redefining the variable. And thirdly, your link has no content:

```
var u = 'somewebsite';
var q = '<a href="'+u+'">';
q += u;
q += '</a>';
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `+=` when initialising a variable (using `var`).  It is only legal to use `=`, and this would work in your case:

```
var u = 'somewebsite';
var q = '<a href="'+u+'">';
q += '</a>';
```

Note that the final `var` is redundant, because `q` is already declared.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few problems here:

- You should initialise `q` to an empty string before appending to it with `+=`
- `var` declares a new variable. You may only declare each variable once.

  ```
  var q = '';
  q += '<...>';
  ```
- Your link has no text in it which explains why you might not see any visual output.

Answer (score 0):

You're never initializing q as a blank string.  Try adding

```
var q = '';
```

to the top half of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes.. I hate concatenating strings by "+". Have a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp.

```
var q = '<a href="'.concat(u).concat('"/>')
```